# Links must be opened at new tab

Tags: html, button, hyperlink

I have a webpage which have buttons on it. I add the buttons with the code block below. How can I add opening links at new tab features to those buttons. Code is like that

```
var appList = [{
    name: "<small>Clever.com</small>",
    grades: "K-12",
    url: "https://clever.com",
    thumbnail: "clever.png"
  },
  {
    name: "Learning.com",
    grades: "K-12",
    url: "http://login.learning.com/",
    thumbnail: "learning.png"
  }
];
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Basically, you want to set the target attribute on the link. IE target="_blank". Please take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 1):

If your code is generating pure HTML use `target` attribute for the `<a/>` tag.
Example:

```
<a href="page.html" target="_BLANK">Open in new tab</a>
```